# Can someone explain implicit "for loops" to me?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am very sorry, I do not understand implicit for loops. So I thought I could ask whether someone will explain this a bit more for me.

I have - under great pains - written the following implicit for loop:

```
ueberdata= [1,5,2,6,1,2,3,4,1,3,5,6]
order = [1,3,5]
ind = [list(ueberdata).index(i) for i in order]
```

this gives me the indices of the first occurrences of the stuff in order.

```
ind : 0,6,2
```

So far so fine. Now I want to expand this example. Maybe ueberdata is bigger. Maybe I would now like to have ALL the indices. And I am stumped. I have to nest these for loops somehow. Can someone help me understand this good enough to solve this problem?

Some clarification (sorry guys, i really need to express myself better):
What i essentially want to do is plot a dataset. I have these 3 types of datapoints i want to see on my plot. Now my dataset is of course longer than 3 :). And I want to plot another column, so I need those indices. Sorry for telling that just now, but I thought it might distract from my question. I want to plot all datapoints in my file, not just the first set.

Comment: They are called *list comprehensions*. Google "list comprehension tutorial" for some pointers.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Isn't the correct answer `ind : 0,6,1` ?

Comment: @Robᵩ is correct for the _first_occurrence of `5`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's called a "[list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)".

Your code could be made simpler, not sure why you're re-creating the list when you already have it:

```
ind = [uberdata.index(i) for i in order]
```

If you want more indices, just make `order` longer.

Comment: Thanks, it seems it was already corrected by Robᵩ.

Answer (score 2):

If you want all the indices, you could do it like this

```
>>> ueberdata= [1,5,2,6,1,2,3,4,1,3,5,6]
>>> order = [1,3,5]
>>> [[i for i,j in enumerate(ueberdata) if j==k] for k in order]
[[0, 4, 8], [6, 9], [1, 10]]
```

If the lists can be quite large, it's more efficient to create a helper defaultdict

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> D = defaultdict(list)
>>> orderset = set(order)
>>> for i,j in enumerate(ueberdata):
...  if j in orderset:
...   D[j].append(i)
... 
>>> [D[i] for i in order]
[[0, 4, 8], [6, 9], [1, 10]]
```

Comment: Yeah, that was how I read the OP too.

Comment: sorry, i want to do something else i think. upvoted for your troubles :)

Answer (score 1):

From [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), a list comprehension can be read as

> "brackets containing an expression followed by a for clause, then zero
>   or more for or if clauses. The result will be a new list resulting
>   from evaluating the expression in the context of the for and if
>   clauses which follow it."

```
[list(ueberdata).index(i) for i in order]
```

is, in a sense, similar to

```
ind=[]
for i in order:
  ind.append(list(ueberdata).index(i))
```

It does not depend on the size of the lists, answering your first question.

For getting all indexes, I would use a auxiliar function, with something like

```
lambda value : [x for x in range(len(ueberdata)) if ueberdata[x] == value]
```